# GraphFrames: find undirectional motif path

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

I'm using GraphFrames motifs to find a path between 3 nodes (a, b, and c) in my graph. This works quite well, but unfortunately I need to find undirected paths.

How do I build an undirected graph or find a motif path that can navigate undirected edges?

```
val motifs = g.find("(a)-[e1]->(b); (b)-[e2]->(c)")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GF is directed graph by nature and implementation. You can just union result fo all "arrow" combinations:

```
val patterns = Seq(
    "(a)-[e1]->(b); (b)-[e2]->(c)", 
    "(b)-[e1]->(a); (b)-[e2]->(c)" , 
    "(a)-[e1]->(b); (c)-[e2]->(b)", 
    "(b)-[e1]->(a); (c)-[e2]->(b)") 
patterns.map(g.find(_).select("a", "e1", "b", "e2", "c")).reduce(_ union _).show
```

Comment: Better way to do the same could be to add pair edges (with opposite direction) to the graph.